# Calling a C function in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, intel, function-calls

Despite I searched everywhere I couldn't find any solution to my problem.The problem is that I I defined a function "hello_world() " in a C file "hello.c" and I want to call this function in an assembly file . "hello_assembly.asm" .Can anyone help me ? 
Thank you.

Comment: With which assembler, compiler, operating system and linker are you trying to do this?

Comment: Where and how exactly did you search?

Comment: Look in your compiler's documentation for "assembly language binding conventions" or something resembling that. The exact details vary from compiler to compiler and architecture to architecture.

Comment: If your C compiler permits inline assembly (some do),  you may find it easier to call assembly from C. Or you may not, depending on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I use gcc assembler ,ubuntu OS,gcc linker . @ElliottFrisch

Comment: I searched almost every pages in Google ,I might be doing smth wrong or misunderstanding the problem.Sorry for that @Andreas

Comment: @ÜmitBilgin You can't easily call C functions from assembly because you (usually!) want a standard library. Using inline assembler in "C" is much easier.

Comment: Then I might be misunderstanding the problem . Thank you for your helps @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Elliott, you can indeed call C from assembler -- you just have to link your assembler program not only with the C code but with the C libraries needed to support it.

Comment: You might want to look at [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/) and [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/).

Comment: Read about calling convention, also you should tag the architecture to the question, otherwise you may not have the correct answer

Comment: Are you trying to call the C function from a line of code which is physically located in your assembly language file ? i.e., are you trying to do something like this ? `call hello_world` where that line is in your file  `hello_assembly.asm` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could check the below example which might give some idea.

```
\#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        signed int a, b;
        a=5,b=25;
        mymul(&a,&b);
        printf("\nresult=%d",b);
        return 0;
}
```

mymul is a function which is being written in assembly language in file called mymul.S

Below is the code for mymul.S

```
.globl mymul
mymul:
        pushl %ebp            # save the old base pointer register
        movl %esp, %ebp       #copy the stack pointer to base pointer register
        movl 8(%ebp), %eax    # get the address of a 
        movl 12(%ebp), %ebx   # get the address of b
        xchg (%eax), %ecx     # we get the value of a and store it in ecx
        xchg (%ebx), %edx     # we get the value of b and stored it in edx
        imul %ecx,%edx        # do the multiplication
        xchg %ecx, (%eax)     #save the value back in a
        xchg %edx, (%ebx)     # save the value back in b
        movl %ebp, %esp       # get the stack pointer back to ebp
        popl %ebp             #restore old ebp
        ret                   #back to the main function
```

We use the command "cc" to compile our above programs

```
$ cc mymul.S mul.c -o mulprogram
```

In the mul.c when we call mymul, we are passing address of a and b , and these address    are getting pushed to the stack.  When the execution of program enters the mymul function, the stack looks like this: addressofb,addressofa, returnaddress, oldebp

we get the value stored in the address of a and address of b using xchg(we could use movl here) , do the multiplication and save the result in b.

I hope the above program helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your help .My actual problem is calling a function defined in a C file from assembly. It is smth like :
(Hello.c
hello_world(){printf("Hello World");
)
(Hello.asm
extern hello_world
...
call hello_world
..
)

Answer (score 2):

[gcc calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl)

The gcc documentation should spell this out in more detail.

If you couldn't find documentation for your compiler and environment, I'd suggest you  compile your C function to an assembler listing and look at how it expects arguments to be passed in and what it leaves on the stack when exiting.